# Trouble printing in C

Tags: c, for-loop, printing

I'm trying to use a for-loop to print out numbers with a step of 0.1 and my output is coming out weird.

My code:

```
    int main()
{
    float i;
    for(i=1.0;(int) i<=9;i=i+0.1)
    {
        printf("%f ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs everything just fine up until 2.700000 and then goes 2.799999,2.899999,2.999999 etc. What's going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Try `printf("%.2f ", i);` does it work?